# why do we assume unity feedback system when designing a controller for a system?

Tags: control, feedback

why do we assume unity feedback system when designing a controller for a system? Please guide on this issue. It's urgent. Thanks!

Comment: John C. - Welcome :-) This is effectively a repeat of [your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570824/why-unity-feedback-is-used) and so it will be merged with that one. Please do *not* repeat questions here, as it is classed as "noise" and is not allowed. You will see more site rules in the [tour] and [help]. Thanks.